# How to update value on a comma separated string in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I update/replace a value on a comma separated string column?

i.e:

```
 121720 |    121716 | false,true,34,1,1,true,1,true
 118220 |    118191 | false,true,731,11,11,true,11,true
 142125 |    142037 | false,true,34,28,28,true,28,true
 182105 |    182012 | false,true,34,3,3,true,3,true,,
 185268 |    185191 | false,true,34,2,2,true,2,true,,
```

How to replace just the second value on the strings (true) for (false)?
What if I want to replace it in a different "position" like sixth or eighth?

I have been able to use the split_part function on `SELECT` but not on `UPDATE`.

Comment: Your current table design is maximally bad.  Even if someone gives you a query, he will simply become an enabler of bad design.  Instead, move each CSV value to a separate row.

Comment: Tim is right. Rather then finding a way to do this, you should fix your data model.

Comment: I couldn't agree more @TimBiegeleisen it is not a pretty design, but it won't change in near future, as much as I would like to, so I still have this situation to fix. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you should give serious thought to changing your table design.  Here is a query which replaces the second CSV value from `true` to `false`:

```
update your_table
set col = regexp_replace(col, '(.*?),true,(.*)', '\1,false,\2')
```

The problem with this query, if it works, is that you would possibly need another regex for the other columns.  And if you ever add or remove CSV columns all the regex you wrote might break or become invalid.

Comment: Thanks very much @timbiegeleisen. Only thing I noticed was that I had to remove the 'g' otherwise the next true would also be replaced.

Comment: That (removing the 'g' ) dealt with the subsequent replace. But I am still unable to make it "count" the intervals/position even after changing the \2 for the desired position, for example 6 or 8.  When I start "playing" with that I am not totally in control of the results of the updates ... yet. But thanks that helped me a lot.

Comment: As mentioned, you would need a different regex for the other positions.  Really you should invest time into fixing your data model rather than going down this path.

Answer (score 0):

do you really need regexpres?

how about creating a function like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION csvupdate(csv text, target_upd text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare 
a  text[];
r record;
begin
a :=  string_to_array($1,',');

FOR r IN select  (string_to_array(zz,':')) [1] ::integer id , (string_to_array(zz,':'))[2] ::text  val  from (   select unnest(string_to_array($2,',')) zz  )q1
loop
a[r.id] := r.val;
end loop;

return array_to_string(a,',');
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;

select csvupdate('true,false,1,3,4,false','1:false,4:33')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @longbeard_boldy, but the previous answer solved the case, I haven't tested your solution (yet). Turns out the task was simpler as I could update all "true" to "false" on the string in the end.